# HTTP Get returning Null from JSON string hosted on localhost:5000

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http

I am hosting a local http server, trying to take data from my Python backend and parse it into my Flutter app.

I'm using Flask with Python 3.9 and it is working, I can see the data on localhost:5000 and it updates correctly. I'm trying to fetch it into my Flutter app and display the data in a text box but am getting an error.

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I have checked to see if I am parsing the data correctly, as this looks like it's not doing it. Here is my code for getting the data from the server:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/gps'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('something messed up');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String lat;
  final String latD;
  final String long;
  final String longD;
  final String date;
  final String time;
  final String sv;

  const Album({
    required this.lat,
    required this.latD,
    required this.long,
    required this.longD,
    required this.date,
    required this.time,
    required this.sv,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      lat: json['lat'],
      latD: json['latD'],
      long: json['long'],
      longD: json['longD'],
      date: json['date'],
      time: json['time'],
      sv: json['sv'],
    );
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this turns the data into a Map of Strings.

This is the code where I attempt to display the data.

```
class _GPSState extends State<GPS> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }
```

```
      body: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('GPS LAT'),
                    subtitle: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                      future: futureAlbum,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          print(snapshot.data!.lat);
                          return Text(snapshot.data!.lat);
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                        }

                        // By default, show a loading spinner.
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I got this example directly from the Flutter documentation, tested it with another JSON server and it worked, but now it is returning null.

My JSON file looks like this (coordinates changed though, dont really want to broadcast my location to everyone)

```
{
"alt":"7.0",
"date":"2022-11-04",
"la_dir":"N",
"lat":"52.45063566666666",
"ln_dir":"W",
"long":"-117.36322",
"sv":"12",
"time":"22:32:47"
}
```

I followed the example on the Flutter documentation and got it to work with a different JSON file hosted on a different server, and did exactly the same thing with this, but to no luck.

I am wondering if the issue is that I am hosting it locally, or whether I need to convert the Album into something else before I try to pick things out of it?

I'm relatively new to Flutter and Dart, only been working on this for a few weeks now, any help would be appreciated.

This is also my first post on StackOverflow so let me know if I should change or add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Dart Extractor fromJson must receive same key name that are present in JSON parsed from website.

```
  lat: json['lat'],
  latD: json['latD'],
  long: json['long'],
  longD: json['longD'],
  date: json['date'],
  time: json['time'],
  sv: json['sv'],
```

Should be

```
alt : json['alt']
date  : json['date']
```

You can also modify names in Key names in JSON File it self

```
 {
"alt":"7.0",
"date":"2022-11-04",
"la_dir":"N",
"lat":"52.45063566666666",
"ln_dir":"W",
"long":"-117.36322",
"sv":"12",
"time":"22:32:47"
}
```

Like here it can be renamed as la_dit to latD

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem It works fine now. I appreciate it!